# `pivothigh` has inconsistent results for 1D

Tags: request, pivot, pine-script, pine-script-v5

The `request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ta.pivothigh(i_leftBars, 10))` on a chart timeframe other than 1 day shows different pivot dates from `ta.pivothigh(i_leftBars, 10)` when the current chart is on a 1 day timeframe. Is there a way to get the pivothigh (and pivotlow) to show the same day? My goal is to use the pivot dates to anchor a VWAP line.

Here is the code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("DEBUG: Pivot High and Low", overlay=true)

i_leftBars = input(10, title="Bars to the Left")
i_rightBars = input(10, title="Bars to the Right")

ph = ta.pivothigh(i_leftBars, i_rightBars)
pl = ta.pivotlow(i_leftBars, i_rightBars)

phD = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ta.pivothigh(i_leftBars, i_rightBars))
plD = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", ta.pivotlow(i_leftBars, i_rightBars))

plot(ph, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3, color= color.red)
plot(pl, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3, color= color.green)
plot(phD, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=5, color= color.orange)
plot(plD, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=5, color= color.blue)
```

Here is the output on a 4 hour timeframe.
https://www.tradingview.com/x/T8Z71wbw/

The pivots don't even land on the same day. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lookahead in request function.
please read this to know more about lookahead.**(very important)**
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html#lookahead

also, you can use one request to get all data you need from same symbol and timeframe.

also, I turn on gaps in request function.
see this for more info:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html#gaps

You can change lookahead and gaps parameters to see the effects on chart.

sorry my English Language not help me for more explain.

```
//@version=5
indicator("DEBUG: Pivot High and Low", overlay=true)

i_leftBars = input(10, title="Bars to the Left")
i_rightBars = input(10, title="Bars to the Right")

ph = ta.pivothigh(i_leftBars, i_rightBars)
pl = ta.pivotlow(i_leftBars, i_rightBars)

[phD, plD] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [ph, pl], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on)

plot(ph, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3, color= color.red)
plot(pl, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=3, color= color.green)
plot(phD, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=5, color= color.orange)
plot(plD, style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=5, color= color.blue)
```